# How to find the object a function belongs to?

Tags: javascript

Given a function, is there a way to find out the object that holds it?

```
var dog = { 
  bark: function() { alert('dfd') },
  name: 'Bill'
}

function getNameFromBark(barkFunc){
   //How to implement this method?
}

getNameFromBack(dog.bark); //I would like this to return Bill.
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Not possible, nor should it be. What exactly are you trying to do? $20 says there's a much simpler way to do it.

Comment: I am actually trying to invoke barkFunc inside getNameFromBack without changing context.

Comment: And unfortunately I don't have any control over the dog object...

Comment: So you can't _getNameFromBack(dog);_ and you're limited to _getNameFromBack(dog.bark);_?

Comment: Hm, then maybe pass a anonymous function that invokes `dog.bark` to your `getNameFromBack` and let `getNameFromBack` invoke the anonymous function. Could that help? `getNameFromBack` wouldn't know about dog or bark but it would get the result of dog.bark.

Comment: Yeah, that could work too. I am trying to design an api, so having to use an anonymous function might be less desirable for asking user to passing the dog as context.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LAf9G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `dog.name`?

Functions can be bound to an object. It can access the properties of that object using the `this` keyword. You can rebind functions with the `bind` function, which changes the value of `this`.

There is **no** way that I know of to ask a function what it is bound to.

like:

```
var my_func = dog.bark; // removing `dog` from the reference
my_func.getBoundObject().name; // would return Bill
```

Comment: _this_ will only point to the _dog_ when a function is invoked with context, ie. _dog.bark();_

Comment: I think with the current constructor `this` is just the global object. You'd need a proper constructor.

Comment: If you do _func = dog.bark; func();_ then _this_ inside _bark_ (_func_ is now _bark_) will point to global object (Window), and not _dog_.

Comment: Is there a way to invoke the bark function inside getNameFromBark without changing its bound object to global? Of course, the getNameFromBark doesn't have a hold to the dog object.

Comment: No. If you pass _bark_ to _getNameFromBark_ via arguments, it's automatically bound to global object. So there is no way to get _dog_ in _getNameFromBark_ when calling _getNameFromBark(dog.bark);_ At least as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you omittones, I think that answers the question. I will have to pass in both the context and the function if I need to invoke it without changing context.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could use prototypes here:

```
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype = {

  getName: function() {
    return this.name;
  },

  bark: function() {
    alert('dfd');
  }

};

var dog = new Dog('Bill');
console.log(dog.getName()); //=> 'Bill'
```

Comment: It seems that you misunderstood my question.

Comment: I might but I think this is a XY problem, thus my solution.

Comment: It is indeed a XY problem, however your Y isn't the real one either. I am actually trying to invoke barkFunc inside getNameFromBack without changing context.

Comment: Try to explicitly set the context like: `function getNameFromBark(barkFunc){
   barkFunc.call(dog);
}` but I don't know if this is quite what you need. What is the code for? Prototypes won't do?

Comment: I don't have control over how dog was written. I understand now that I have to pass in both dog and the function to the getNameFromBark function

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written your code, `dog.bark` is just a function reference and has no association with any specific object once you've passed it as `dog.bark` so there is no way to get any other data from the object when you just pass it like this:

```
getNameFromBark(dog.bark);
```

Inside of `getNameFromBack()`, the passed argument is just a function.  Methods in javascript are just properties on an object and once you retrieve the property value, it's just a function.  There is no object reference associated with the function itself.  So short of just using `dog.name` to reference the global object `dog`, you can't get `dog.name` from within that function any other way.

---

Now, you could restructure you code any number of ways to allow that.  For example, you could pass the object instead of the function:

```
getNameFromBark(dog);
```

And, then inside of `getNameFromBark()`, you can access the `.name` property from the passed in object.

---

Or, in a bit of an abuse of the object system, you could put a property on the function itself that contains the name:

```
var dog = { 
  bark: function() { alert('dfd') },
  name: 'Bill'
}

// assign name property to the bark function too
dog.bark.name = dog.name;

function getNameFromBark(barkFunc){
   //How to implement this method?
   return(barkFunc.name);
}

getNameFromBack(dog.bark); //I would like this to return Bill.
```

But, this is probably not the best way to design your code.  If we understood the real problem you were trying to solve, we could probably suggest a much better object-oriented architecture that doesn't duplicate properties.