# Do not modify context even using a function that modifies the context

Tags: javascript, class, methods, this

Maybe the title sounds a little bit weird (*please improve it*) -- but I need a solution for the following scenario. I have the following code:

```
var Foo = function () {
    this._hello = "world!";
};

Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log(this._hello);
};

var f = new Foo();
f.bar(); // => "world!"
f.bar.apply(this); // => undefined
```

I know that `apply` changes the context, so inside of `bar`, `this` will be the global object (at the second call).

But what I need is to access `this` from `Foo` function. A solution that I see would be:

```
var Foo = function () {
   var self = this;
   self._hello = "world!";
   self.bar = function () {
      console.log(self._hello);
   };
};
```

However, I would choose not to have method declarations inside of another function.

I'd prefer to define methods same column level (just for code style):

```
var Foo = ...;
Foo.prototype.method = ...;
```

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Just don't bother indenting your code.

Comment: That's not the "scope", it's the *context of the call*

Comment: Why would you use `apply` on `bar` at all? How does your call look that is not simply `f.bar()`?

Comment: @Bergi I want to be able to do: `f = new Foo(); something.method(f.bar);`. In this case `f.bar` is called with another scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to tackle [these kinds of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback). Instead of `something.method(f.bar)` call `something.method(f.bar.bind(f))` to get the `bar` method always called on the expected context (`f`).

If you don't want to use `bind` in every location where you pass `bar` around as a callback, you can also put it in the constructor to create a dedicated bound function for every instance by default:

```
function Foo() {
    this._hello = "world!";
    this.bar = this.bar.bind(this);
}
Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log(this._hello);
};

var f = new Foo;
something.method(f.bar); // works!
```

Comment: Should be `this._hello`

Comment: This is the correct solution, however I do not recommend it because it's not memory friendly I guess.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: Why? It shouldn't be less memory friendly than the closure solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this by assigning a function to the prototype like this.

Unless you assign something to `f.bar` directly (as in your second example, and Bergi's answer), the value you will get for `f.bar` is a reference to the function you assigned to the prototype's property `Foo.prototype.bar`. This will be exactly the same function object for any other object that has `Foo.prototype` as a prototype. There is no reference to `f` in this function object.

So when you call `f.bar()`, how does `this` refer to the value of `f`? It is a special syntax, that basically equates to `f.bar.apply(f)`. It is only the fact that you use this method-call syntax that sets `this` to the value of `f`. Any other reference to `f.bar` will just evaluate to the prototype's single, shared function object.

If you call it with `f.bar.apply(somethingElse)`, `this` is now set to `somethingElse`, and all association with `f` is lost.

It's not a question of `apply(...)` *changing* scope. `fn.apply(x)` sets `this` to `x` within `fn`, whereas `y.fn()` sets `this` to `y`.

Similarly, in your example if you assign `f.bar` to a variable and then invoke it via the variable instead of using the method-call syntax `f.bar()`, your `this` will be the `window` object (if running in a browser) and again you'll get `undefined`.

```
var func=f.bar; // now func === Foo.prototype.bar
func(); // => undefined
```

See also [How to find the object a function belongs to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543291/how-to-find-the-object-a-function-belongs-to)